# Unable to parse DateTime with a custom format

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

After reading some other similar questions and trying their suggestions, I'm still unable to get my time to parse into a DateTime-

```
string time1 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Reminders\Reminder1Time.txt");
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(time1, "hh:mm:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dateTimePicker1.Value = dt1;
```

`time1` is a string value of `9:00 AM` Other questions have mentioned to use `ParseExact` to specify a custom format, but it's still not parsing.

The error I get thrown is on the second line

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How would I get the dateTimePicker1 to display the value from the `time1` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a stray colon and an extra `h` if you are expecting a 12 hour clock 1-12 without a leading zero and the AM PM marker with whitespace.

Try: `h:mm tt`

All of the formatting options are buried in the documentation, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This did it- did not even think to use a single `h`. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp Have a look through those docs, you'll be surprised what you can do with parsing dates, same goes for numbers / currencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
var datefromFile = File.ReadAllText(FILELOCATION);
var format = "dd-MM-yyy hh:mm:ss,fff";
var formattedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFromFile, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Make your format Explicit, remember dd for date capital MM for month and yyyy for year. hh for hour mm for minutes and ss for seconds.

MSDN Formats:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, I don't see it. Either the question is incorrect or this answer is incorrect.

Comment: This still doesn't work. I am specifying the format; the problem seems to be with the string maybe?

Comment: its DateTime struct which means it requires the date AND the time, hes only specified the time. You have to be explicit.

Comment: If it still doesnt work then the problem is the actual content in the file specified. @EyeSeeSharp maybe you should print the actual content of that file so we can see whats wrong.

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp then could you check the correct answer :-)

Comment: @TheAkhemist No you don't. It just parses the date part as today so far as I can tell in my testing. I was more drawing attention to the fact that your custom format was also wildly incorrect.